# How to load manifest.json in React JS app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I have a React app setup with Webpack(and not CRA). I am trying to make it progressive by adding a manifest.json file parallel to index.html. While running the app I am getting below error.

```
GET http://localhost:8090/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Also, if I look at the `dist` folder after running the `build` command, there is no `manifest.json` file copied to `dist`. I have tried using the webpack's `file-loader` plugin, but it also doesn't work. Below is the `webpack.config.js` snippet:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.(js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader' },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
        //{ test: /\.html$/, use: ['html-loader'] },
        { test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/, use: { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[name].[ext]', outputPath: 'assets/img' } } },
        { test: /\.(json)$/, use: { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[name].[ext]', outputPath: './' } } }
    ]
},
```

Below is `index.html` snippet:

```
<head>
   <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

What you can do to load `manifest.json` are following steps:

- put the `manifest.json` in the `static` folder at the root of your project.
- in your `index.html` : `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">`

To know if your file was load, check in Chrome DevTools, inside Application => Manifest

Answer (score 1):

If the answer above doesn't work for you (like in my case), try the **app-manifest-webpack-plugin**.
It builds out the *manifest.json* file for you when you run `npm run build` or `yarn run build`.
It also has numerous configurations, making it very flexible.